# If the area integrals of a function are zero, is it in the image of the Laplacian?

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations

I know very little about analysis or PDEs, so apologies if this is an elementary question.

Let $g \in C^0(\mathbf{R}^2, \mathbf{R})$ and suppose that there exists $f \in C^2(\mathbf{R}^2, \mathbf{R})$ with $\Delta f = g$. Here $\Delta = \partial^2/\partial x^2 + \partial^2/\partial y^2$ is the Laplacian on $\mathbf{R}^2$. If $\Omega \subseteq \mathbf{R}^2$ is compact with piecewise $C^\infty$ boundary $\partial \Omega$ then
\begin{align}
\int_\Omega g = \int_\Omega \nabla \cdot \nabla f = \int_{\partial \Omega} \nabla f = 0,
\end{align}
by the divergence theorem (unless I am mistaken).

If $g \in C^0(\mathbf{R}^2, \mathbf{R})$ with
\begin{align}
\int_\Omega g = 0
\end{align}
for all compact $\Omega \subseteq \mathbf{R}^2$ with piecewise $C^\infty$ boundary, does there exist $f \in C^2(\mathbf{R}^2, \mathbf{R})$ with $\Delta f = g$?

Comment: If $\int_\Omega g=0$ for all compact $\Omega$, then $g\equiv 0$ , and $f=1$ works.

Comment: @whpowell96 what does $g \equiv 0$ mean?

Comment: Your condition on $g$ implies that $g$ must be identically zero. @JosephHarrison

Comment: Note that $g(x)  = \lim_{r\to 0} \frac{1}{| B_r(x)|} \int_{B_r(x)} g$ for all continuous $g$.

Comment: @ArcticChar Thanks for sharing that nice fact and I see how it implies that $g$ should be identically zero. Was my use of the divergence theorem incorrect? Otherwise it would seem to imply that the image of the Laplacian is zero

Comment: No matter how much integral condition you impose, this is impossible. You can find a function g such that no C^2 f solves the equation in any neighborhood of 0. See https://www.math.ualberta.ca/~xinweiyu/527.1.11f/lec11.pdf

Comment: I don't see why $\int_{\partial \Omega } \nabla f \cdot n $ is zero...

Comment: @ArcticChar Do we not have $\int_{\partial \Omega} \nabla f = f(p) - f(p) = 0$ for some point $p \in \partial \Omega$?

Comment: No. You are perhaps thinking of the derivative of a curve parameter using the boundary, which would integrate to zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $g = \Delta f$. It is certainly okay to say
\begin{align}
\int_\Omega g = \int_{\partial \Omega} \nabla f \cdot \hat{n}
\end{align}
where $\hat{n}$ is a smooth normal to $\partial \Omega$, but the latter integral is not necessarily zero. This is because this is a flux integral not a line integral. We do have
\begin{align}
\int_{\partial \Omega} \nabla f \cdot \hat{t} = 0
\end{align}
by the fundamental theorem for line integrals, but here $\hat{t}$ is a smooth tangent to the boundary.

In particular, functions $g$ in the image of the Laplacian do not satisfy
\begin{align}
\int_\Omega g = 0
\end{align}
for all compact $\Omega$ unless they are zero.